# Unable to get values from from XML in R

Tags: r, xml

I am trying to get values of XML using code

```
f_name <- getNodeSet(root, "/records/record/person/names/first_name")

#O/P- 
[[1]]
<first_name>Rahul</first_name>

[[2]]
<first_name>Jay</first_name>

[[3]]
<first_name>John</first_name>

[[4]]
<first_name>Umberto</first_name>
```

Now I am unable to pick the values from all First_name tags and store into dataframe.
Plz Help

Comment: What precisely do you want as output from the list?

Comment: Only the names like Rahul , Jay not the tag names.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gsub`

```
fname<-list('<first_name>Rahul</first_name>','<first_name>Jay</first_name>','<first_name>John</first_name>')
gsub('(first_name|<|/|>)','',fname)
#[1] "Rahul" "Jay"   "John"
```

Answer (score 0):

use sapply to get the values - loop over the nodes and get the content as a string:
names <- xmlSApply(f_name, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))